# Logger file needs to be generated in dynamic location

Tags: java, log4j

I tried in search of this question, this is my latest requirement.

The question is ***I need my log files to be created in respective location, and the location is decided in runtime.***

I am using following configuration in properties file.

```
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.File=C:/CABS_Exstream/project/svn_code/cabs_ex‌​stream_sai/logs/cabs.log log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.Append = true 
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.maxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.maxFileSize=5MB 
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %x - %m%n`
```

Could anyone please help to find the solution.

Comment: what logging framework you are using ?

Comment: I am using log4j framework. presently I am using following configuration in properties file.   log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.File=C:/CABS_Exstream/project/svn_code/cabs_exstream_sai/logs/cabs.log
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.Append = true
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.maxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %x - %m%n

Comment: possible duplicate of [a number of log4j config questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911784/a-number-of-log4j-config-questions)

Comment: Hi RC, the given example is not working. Could you please let me know if you have any other solution. I tried in the following way. In Java as System.setProperty("processDir","C:\\CABS_Exstream\\logTest"); In properties file as log4j.appender.cabsLoggerTestRoll.File=${processDir}/test.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet to configure your log4j properties file,

```
          String dynamicLogDir = "C:/CABS_Exstream/project/svn_code/cabs_ex‌​stream_sai/logs";
          System.setProperty("logDir", dynamicLogDir);
          Properties p = new Properties();
          p.load(new FileInputStream("<log4j property file path>\\log4j.properties"));
          PropertyConfigurator.configure( p );
```

And write your lod4j.properties file likes this;

```
     log4j.appender.cabsLoggerCoreRoll.File=${logDir}/cabs.log
```

Comment: Thanks Sai, I just have solved this but with somewhat different way.